# While inserting data to two tables using stored procedure I am getting a mismatch error

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table called `CompanyMaster_tbl` with a table structure as follows.

```
Cid  CompanyName  Deleted
```

and another table named `DepartmentMaster_tbl`,with a table structure as follows.

```
dtld  dtname dtphone dtemail  cid deleted
```

I've written a stored procedure for inserting data into these tables as follows.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertDetails](
@companyName varchar(150),
@dname varchar(150),
@dphon varchar(150),
@deleted int,
@cid  int OUTPUT
) AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO [dbo].CompanyMaster_tbl
    VALUES (@companyName)
    select @cid=cid
    from [dbo].CompanyMaster_tbl
    WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND cid = scope_identity()

    insert into DepartmentMaster_tbl
    values(@dname,
    @dphon)
    end
```

When I execute this SP,  i am getting error like this:

```
Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this , mention coloumn name

```
      INSERT INTO [dbo].CompanyMaster_tbl (CompanyName )  
       VALUES (@companyName)


     INSERT into DepartmentMaster_tbl (dname,dphon)
        values(@dname, @dphon)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are giving wrong number of values to the table i.e. you have two columns in table CompanyMaster_tbl(i think your cid is identity(auto generated) there fore i did not mention it) but you can give only one value to the table, and same thing applies for DepartmentMaster_tbl. if you can't give the values to the table then mention column names in the insert statement otherwise give all column value
e.g.

```
Insert into CompanyMaster_tbl(CompanyName) values(@companyName)
```

or

```
Insert into CompanyMaster_tbl values(@companyName, @deleted)
```